# Update specific value in named range?

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have the following function which retrieves a value from a named range:

[image]

```
Function getSetting(settingName As String)
    getSetting = Application.VLookup(settingName, Range("rSettings"), 2, True)
End Function
```

Now I can easily say `myColor = getSetting("myColor")` and it will return "blue" or whatever.

What I want to do now is *update* that value.

```
Function updateSetting(settingName As String, newValue As String)
    ?????
End Function
```

Ideas?

Comment: Hey! Where do you get the color from? Or rather the color of what?

Comment: Added screenshot of my Named Range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One you will need to use a sub not a function.

Two you can use the [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method to find the cell.  Then use offset to change the value.

```
Sub updateSetting(settingName As String, newValue As String)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("rSettings").Find(settingName)
    c.Offset(, 1).Value = newValue
End Sub
```

Also as to your first function, personal preference is not to use worksheet function where vba function can be used.  It is slower.

```
Function getSetting(settingName As String)
     Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("rSettings").Find(settingName)
    getSetting = c.Offset(, 1).Value 
End Function
```

Comment: Yeah I actually had a sub in my code but for the question I copied and pasted the getSetting function :)

Comment: Also this worked like a charm, and thanks for the tip on the getSetting function!

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the location of each *settingName* in the range using the Match function:

> **WorksheetFunction.Match method**
>
> Returns the relative position of an item in an array (array: Used to build single formulas that produce multiple results or that operate on a group of arguments that are arranged in rows and columns. An array range shares a common formula; an array constant is a group of constants used as an argument.) that matches a specified value in a specified order. Use MATCH instead of one of the LOOKUP functions when you need the position of an item in a range instead of the item itself.

```
dim index
index = Match(settingName,Range("settings"),0)
```

Comment: `Match` is what I was working on but I kept getting `Error 2042` or something.  Thanks for the answer, but @Scott Craner's works great and makes the most sense to me.